# How to make a diagram from arrays in java?

Tags: java

My program needs to draw a diagram like this:

```
    ---
    ---         xxx
    ---         xxx
+++ ---         xxx
+++ ---     ooo xxx
+++ ---     ooo xxx
+++ ---     ooo xxx
+++ --- *** ooo xxx
+++ --- *** ooo xxx
+++ --- *** ooo xxx
```

From this data:

```
private static final int[] DATA = {15, 21, 7, 12, 18};

private static final int MAX_HEIGHT = 10;

private static final int COLUMN_WIDTH = 3;

private static final int SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS = 2;

private static final char[] FILLER = {’+’, ’-’, ’*’, ’o’, ’x’};
```

I really need some guidlines on how to make it.

Thanks

Comment: @zengr: It seems way too straightforward for a take-home interview. I guess it could be homework.. hadn't thought of that. I'd delete my answer, but I didn't give him code, just a nudge.

Comment: Yes it is a homework, but i don't need a whole code just some guidlines where i can start coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a commented implementation of your task:

```
public class DiagramMaker {
    private final int[] data;
    private final char[] filler;
    private final int maxHeight;
    private final int columnWidth;
    private final int spacing;

    private int[] colHeights;

    public DiagramMaker(int[] data, char[] filler, int maxHeight, int columnWidth, int spacing) {
        this.data = data;
        this.filler = filler;
        this.maxHeight = maxHeight;
        this.columnWidth = columnWidth;
        this.spacing = spacing;
    }

    /**
        Primary method for writing the chart to StringBuffer
    */
    public render(StringBuffer buffer) {
    //Calculate the heights of all data columns scaled to our maxHeight
        colHeights = DiagramMaker.getColumnHeights(data, maxHeight);
    //Output all of our lines onto StringBuffer
        for (int i=0;i<maxHeight;i++) {
            printLine(buffer, i);
        }
    }

    /**
        Method for printing 1 line of the chart
    */
    public void printLine(StringBuffer buffer, int lineNum) {
    //Go through all columns
        for (int i=0;i<colHeights.length;i++) {
            //Check if current row can be seen on this line
            if (colHeights[lineNum] >= maxHeight-lineNum) {
                DiagramMaker.printColumnLine(buffer, filler[i], columnWidth);
                //Should we draw the spacing
                if (i < colHeights.length-1) {
                    DiagramMaker.printColumnLine(buffer, ' ', spacing);
                }
            }
        }
    }

/**
    Method for filling the given character specified amount of times into StringBuffer. Used for drawing columns and spacers.
*/
    protected static void printColumnLine(StringBuffer buffer, char filler, int width) {
        for (int i=0;i<width;i++) {
            buffer.append(filler);
        }
    }

    /**
        Calculates the maximal data value
    */
    protected static int getMaxData(int[] data) {
        int maxData = 0;
        for (int val : data) {
            if (val > maxData) {
                maxData = val;
            }
        }   
        return maxData;
    }

    /**
        Gets the height of each column given max height and data
    */
    protected static int[] getColumnHeights(int[] data, int maxHeight) {
        int maxData = getMaxData(data)
        int[] heights = new int[data.length];
        for (int i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            //Calculate the scale of this column
            double scale = ((double)data[i])/maxData;
            heights[i] = (int)(scale*data[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not grab the highest value in the array, then countdown from there?
As you countdown, you write a line if each array index is greater than the current threshold.

Answer (score 0):

A few steps :

- create a StringBuilder to get the result
- create a int[] DATA_DIVIDED_BY_2.
- during this creation, get the max, and number of columns
- loop from max to 0 (i)
- loop from 0 to NUMBER_OF_COL - 1 (j)
- if DATA_DIVIDE_BY_2[j] >= i then result.append(FILLER[i]) 3 times + 1 space. else append(4 spaces)
- end loop j, result.append("\n")
- end loop i, print result.toString()

Comment: seams like this is ignoring MAX_HEIGHT, COLUMN_WIDTH and SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS

Comment: @Carlos Yes, it's homework, I just gave some steps, so about Column_width and space_between_columns it's up to koporc to find how to use them ! And about max_height, I forgot it when I wrote my steps :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by rows rather than by columns, so that it can be sent to a device with no access to previous output lines.

1. Scale the data to be between 0 and MAX_HEIGHT.
2. Subtract each scaled value from MAX_HEIGHT to get the number of empty spaces (assuming that the tallest bar is always MAX_HEIGHT high).
3. Loop through the rows. For each row, loop through the columns. For each column, if the current row number is less than the number of white spaces expected for that column, print spaces. Otherwise print the appropriate fill character.